# For Loops and string comparisons

Tags: java, loops

I am reworking a class problem on For Loops and cannot gain a total out of a running score. I attempted to use the string comparisons, but that may be where the problem is. The assignment is:

"Simon Says" is a memory game where "Simon" outputs a sequence of 10 characters (R, G, B, Y) and the user must repeat the sequence. Create a for loop that compares the two strings starting from index 0. For each match, add one point to userScore. Upon a mismatch, exit the loop using a break statement. Ex: The following patterns yield a userScore of 4:

simonPattern: RRGBRYYBGY

userPattern:  RRGBBRYBGY

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimonSays {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      String simonPattern = "";
      String userPattern = "";
      int userScore = 0;
      int i = 0;

      userScore = 0;
      simonPattern = "RRGBRYYBGY";
      userPattern  = "RRGBBRYBGY";

     /* Your solution begins here */

        String ss1 = simonPattern.substring(0, 2);
        String us1 = userPattern.substring(0, 2);

        String ss2 = simonPattern.substring(2, 3);
        String us2 = userPattern.substring(2, 3);

        String ss3 = simonPattern.substring(4, 5);
        String us3 = userPattern.substring(4, 5);

        String ss4 = simonPattern.substring(6, 7);
        String us4 = userPattern.substring(6, 7);

        String ss5 = simonPattern.substring(8, 9);
        String us5 = userPattern.substring(8, 9);

        for (i = 0; i < simonPattern.length(); i++) {
        if (ss1.equals(us1)) {
            userScore = userScore + 1;
        }
        if (ss2.equals(us2)){
            userScore = userScore + 1;
        }
        if (ss3.equals(us3)){
            userScore = userScore + 1;
        }
        if (ss4.equals(us4)){
            userScore = userScore + 1;
        }
        if (ss5.equals(us5)){
            userScore = userScore + 1;
        }
        else{
           break;
        }

    }

      /* ^ Your solution goes here ^ */

      System.out.println("userScore: " + userScore);

      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare strings. Use the `equals()` method instead. For example: `if (ss1.equals(us1)) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you. I made some changes and the total is now 40 instead of 4. I tried to stop the loop with string.length() but I'm still baffled.

Comment: @L.Lab1 What do you think happens when you repeat the exact same code 10 times? `simonPattern` is 10 long, so you loop 10 times, but code inside loop doesn't use `i` for anything, so if 4 are good answers (incl #5), you then add 4 to score, 10 times, for a total of 40.

Comment: Yes, I saw that and did not know how to solve. I am not certain how to set the For Loop statement to interact through in groups of two characters. When I set the i<=5, the loop still addresses one character at a time resulting in 4 points (through index 4), and not going though index 9 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is in your for loop change `if (ss1 == us1)` to `if (ss1.equals(us1))` same with the else if stucture because String is a reference type and not a primitive data type

primitive data types are `int`,`double`,`long`,`float`,`byte`,`short`,`boolean`,`char` and all objects are reference type

```
 public static void main (String [] args) 
 {
    String simonPattern = "";
    String userPattern = "";
    int userScore = 0;


    userScore = 0;
    simonPattern = "RRGBRYYBGY";
    userPattern  = "RRGBBRYBGY";

    String[] simons = new String[5];
    String[] users = new String[5];
    int adder=2;
    int location=0;
    for(int i=0;i<simonPattern.length();i+=2)
    {
        simons[location]=simonPattern.substring(i,adder);
        location++;
        adder+=2;
    }
    adder=2;
    location=0;
    for(int i=0;i<userPattern.length();i+=2)
    {
        users[location]=userPattern.substring(i,adder);
        location++;
        adder+=2;
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < simonPattern.length(); i++) 
    {
            if(users[i].equals(simons[i]))
                userScore++;



    }
    System.out.println(userScore);




    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I made some changes and the total is now 40 instead of 4. I tried to stop the loop with string.length() but I'm still baffled.

Comment: @L.Lab1 I had created some logic for you

Comment: @L.Lab1 or to end the loop you can just put `i=6` to the else statement

Comment: Thank you again, this resulted in a score of 1 for me... instead of 4

Comment: @L.Lab1 why don't you try array of String? I had edited my answer

Comment: @L.Lab1 also you break the loop but you also set the score to 4? the occurence of the break is in the third `substring()` so the score would be two you should rethink of using loop

Comment: Thank you jobeth billien

Comment: @L.Lab1 if this answer your question accept it as an answer by checking it

Answer (score 0):

You correctly changed the loop to iterate length of `simonPattern`. Now you just need to throw away the code inside the loop and actually *use* the iterator variable `i`.

To extract a single character from a string, you could continue to use `substring(i, i+1)` to get a `String` value, but for single characters it's better to use `charAt(i)`.

Also, to increment a variable by 1, it's better to use `userScore++`, instead of `userScore = userScore + 1`, although that does work too.

This means that your code should be:

```
String simonPattern = "RRGBRYYBGY";
String userPattern  = "RRGBBRYBGY";
int userScore = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < simonPattern.length(); i++) {
    char c1 = simonPattern.charAt(i);
    char c2 = userPattern.charAt(i);
    if (c1 != c2)
        break;
    userScore++;
}
System.out.println("userScore: " + userScore); // prints 4
```

Comment: Break the loop on first mismatch!

Comment: @SanketMakani Yeah, I misunderstood goal at first. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider doing it by iterating through the userPattern instead like this:

int userScore = 0;

```
String simonPattern = "RRGBRYYBGY";
String userPattern  = "RRGBBYYBGY";
for (int i = 0; i < userPattern.length(); i++) {
    String p = userPattern.substring(0, 1 + i);
    if (simonPattern.startsWith(p)) {
        userScore = userScore + 1;
    }
}
if (userScore < simonPattern.length()) {
    System.out.println("You got " + userScore + " letters deep out of " + 
            simonPattern.length() + " before you made a mistake.");
}
else { 
    System.out.println("YOU WIN!"); 
}
```